# Any illustration of a sigma algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a non-empty set and assume $\Gamma$ is in $2^X$ satisfying in $A\in \Gamma$ implies $A^c$ is also in $\Gamma$.

We say $A$ is a $G^{\Gamma}_{\delta}$-set if there is a sequence $\{A_n\}$ in $\Gamma$ with $A=\cap A_i$. We also say  $B$ is a $F^{\Gamma}_{\sigma}$-set if there is a sequence $\{A_n\}$ in $\Gamma$ with $A=\cup A_i$.

Let us denote: 
$$\sigma_1:=\{\cup_{1}^{\infty} G_n: G_n ~is ~a~ G^{\Gamma}_{\delta}-set~\}$$
$$\sigma_2:=\{\cap_{1}^{\infty} F_n: G_n ~is ~a~ F^{\Gamma}_{\sigma}-set~\}$$

Question: Is  $\sigma_1\cup\sigma_2$ closed under any countable union? That is, if $A_1,A_2,\cdots$ are in the union $\sigma_1\cup\sigma_2$, then the union $\cup A_n$ is in $\sigma_1\cup\sigma_2$ as well?!

Comment: In general, no this is not so - for example, when $\Gamma$ is the collection of all subsets of $\Bbb R$ that are either open or closed. Clearly $\sigma_1$ is closed under countable unions, and $\sigma_2$ is closed under countable intersections. But If every countable union of sets in $\sigma_2$ were in $\sigma_1 \cup \sigma_2$, then the Borel hierarchy would collapse — no new sets would appear after the third level. But it doesn't collapse: new sets appear at every level $\alpha < \omega_1$.

Comment: Thanks. It was really nice argument.

Comment: Ah thank you, & you're welcome.